# Not able to store string array in Hashmap object

Tags: java

I want to add the string array values to Hashmap. My data has 2 rows and 3 columns.
Here is the code, average and date of birth record is not stored on the hashmap.

```
public class Practice1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
    {
        
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the no. of players");
         int player=sc.nextInt();
         
         String[][] newArray = new String[player][3];
         System.out.println("enter the player_name, average,date_of_birth");
        
             for (int i=0; i<newArray.length; i++) {
                String[] line = sc.next().trim().split(",");
                for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
                    newArray[i][j] = line[j];
                }
             }
         
         HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String,String>();
         for (String[] mapping : newArray) {
             hmap.put(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
           }
     
           
           System.out.println(Arrays.asList(hmap));
       }             
}
```

console output:

```
Enter the no. of players
2
enter the player_name, average,date_of_birth
max,50.2,1985-11-14
war,50.2,1986-10-27
[{max=50.2, war=50.2}]
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? Because you store only name/avg so that's the only output you can get for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By priority,

1. Prefer to create a `Player` class and create a `HashMap<String, Player>` to hold all player information.
2. Second best is to create a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.
3. If you insist of doing it the way you describe in the question, you need a `HashMap<String, String[]>`.

### A Player class

Your `Player` class should have three fields (instance variables), a `String` for the name, a `double` (or a `float`) for the average and a `LocalDate` for the date of birth. You may provide it with a convenience constructor that accepts a line of input, splits it into the three values and throws an exception if the number of values isn’t three, then parses the average into a `double` and the date into a `LocalDate`. Also code a `toString` method so that you objects print in a recognizable way.

Now store your `Player` object into a `HashMap<String, Player>`. Edit: For example after you have created the player object, do

```
    hmap.put(yourPlayer.getName(), yourPlayer);
```

(assuming your `Player` class defines a `getName` method that returns the name).

### HashMap<String, List>

Mixing generic collections like `HashMap<K, V>` with arrays has some liabilities. So I suggest a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. After splitting your input line into a `String` array, wrap it into a list with `Arrays.asList(line)` and store that list into your map.

### If you insist: HashMap<String, String[]>

You may create a map where the keys are strings (as they are in the map you have got now) and the values string arrays. Then you can store the array that you get from `split()` directly as a value into your map (no need to copy the individual strings first unless you have special requirements you haven’t told us).

PS A short way to print the map in this case would be using a lambda:

```
    hmap.forEach((name, arr) -> System.out.println(name + '=' + Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

### What went wrong in your code?

```
             hmap.put(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
```

In this line you are storing a map entry where the name is key and the average is the value. The last entry (column) from the array, the date of birth, is not stored into the map.

Comment: thanks for the response. I prefer to create a Player class and create a HashMap<String, Player>.  I created the Player class. how to store all ways in Map array. I am getting not able to store